# Eclipse me desplega este cartel "multiple markers at this line"

Tags: java

espero me puedan ayudar, me cree una clase que se llama Uso_personas dentro de ella declare otras clases como Personas y Empleados2 (acá es donde esta el error) este último lo llamé así para evitar un error de duplicidad, ya que están dentro del mismo paquete. Copié y pegué la estructura de otra clase que se llama `Empleado1`.

Espero me puedan ayudar, no sé si son suficientes los datos:

> "multiple markers at this line"
>
> - the public type Empleado2 must be defined in ist own file
> - Persona cannot be resolved to a type

```
public class Empleado2 extends Persona {
//ATRIBUTOS


    private double sueldo;

    private Date altaContrato;

    private int Id;

    private static int IdSiguiente = 1;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java sólo admite una clase principal por fichero, que además debe coincidir con el nombre de la clase.
Por tanto necesitas crear un fichero `Empleado2.java` y un fichero `Persona.java`

Comment: Impecable!! intentare aplicarlo. Como soy nuevo me estaba guiando por este curso https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDZUBY0mxv8&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk&index=46. A el si le deja je

Comment: No uses respuestas para añadir comentarios, si una respuesta te soluciona el problema puedes aceptarla (pulsando en el *check* que aparece debajo de las flechas de voto) para marcarla como *respondida*

Comment: Nuevamente gracias!